# C++ empty() and all_of() for checking string is empty or have only digit

Tags: c++11

I'm creating an IO console application and at the inputs i got an 'while' loop with two condition
`empty()` and `all_of()`, the function `all_of()` seems to work properly but when i press enter the `empty()` function not working and just let me to input the next thing in the 'struct'. I'm not sure am i doing it correct..There is the part of the code

```
    cout << "Enter age: ";
    getline(cin, age_str);  
            
    while(!age_str.empty() && !all_of(age_str.begin(), age_str.end(), ::isdigit)){
        
            cout << "--Please Enter an integer-- " << endl;
            cin.clear();
            getline(cin, age_str);          
    
    }
    stringstream(age_str) >> person_arr[n].age;
```

There are a link to the full code : [enter link description here](http://cpp.sh/4x55h5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of the conditional of the `while` is incorrect.

What you need to do is:

1. If the line is empty, get the next line.
2. If the line is not empty and the line has anything other than digits, get the next line.

`!age_str.empty() && !all_of(age_str.begin(), age_str.end(), ::isdigit)` does not do that.

You need to use `age_str.empty() || (!all_of(age_str.begin(), age_str.end(), ::isdigit))`

I always recommend, when in doubt, simplify.

```
while ( !is_input_valid(age_str)) )
{
   ...
}
```

where

```
bool is_input_valid(std::string const& input)
{
   if ( input.empty() )
   {
      return false;
   }

   return std::all_of(input.begin(), input.end(), ::isdigit);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this not fixing it and now all_of() has stopped working too. I was trying the same solution too.

Comment: @Micheal.M, perhaps the problem is in a different place in your program. Please edit your post and post a [mcve].

Comment: Is link to the cpp.sh webiste for a full code works?

Comment: @Micheal.M, it's always better to post the code with your question.

Comment: @Micheal.M, you are using `while(!age_str.empty() ...`. That `!` needs to go. `while ( age_str.empty() ...`

Comment: @R Sahu Oh... I'm sorry i was sure that i removed it. Thank you very much it works!

Comment: @Micheal.M, no problem. Glad I was able to help.